# Add active class for first item element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/87D3/production/_84817743_beckhamfashion.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/9949/production/_84814293_dummy.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using bootstap carousel for example;

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

and as you see my first `.item`class has `.active`class but I want to add it automatically when I remove `.active`class from `.item` class then javascript gave me this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined /works/anitur/js/bootstrap.min.js:6` and I tried to add with this code

```
$(".carousel > .item:first").addClass("active");
```

but nothing change how can I realize what I want ? and by the way is there any way to add carousel control with js not html ?

Comment: $(".carousel .item:first").addClass("active");

Comment: @BùivănNguyện what can be change I didn't understand it's same with my code

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: `$(".carousel > .item:first")` -> direct child use `$(".carousel .item:first")` since `item` is not direct child of `carousel`

Comment: @recruit_man : remove ">" to make it works

Comment: I edit my post to add jsfiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better practice to add classes for a carousel in HTML template itself. Why because the carousel plugins will rebuild the HTML after `document is ready`. However you can try the below code.

```
$(".carousel .item").first().addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried one by one, this code is the correct one to add active class for first item element
.

```
$(".carousel .item:first").addClass("active");
```

For more detail, See the red colored box and arrow in the picture.
You may check it as well in live version, here in the [*running code at JSFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/chetabahana/r7yy5ubg/)

[image: Instagram feed with infinite scrolling functionality | Chetabahana Project - A Way To Win The Market | GitHub Page]

Answer (score 0):

You should correct this
`$(".carousel .item:first").addClass("active");`